# Node.js Firebase Post

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having some problems with Node.js, I have no experience at all.
So I'm trying to write post method, but it's always returning

> Something went wrong

but I can't see where is the problem

Here is the code.

```
exports.createNews = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const newNews = {
    content: req.body.content,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
};

admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('news')
    .add(newNews)
    .then((doc) => {
        res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
        console.error(err);
    });
```

And my post method from postman.

```
{
    "content": "First test",
    "userHandle": "some user"
}
```

Here is console error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more
>   information.
>
> > ```
> >  at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\fireshark-back\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:161:19)
> >  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

did it's job.